# MySql query syntax error DATE_SUB

Tags: mysql, sql, date-format

what's wront with this query?

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM containmentTracker 
WHERE reviewDate < NOW() 
  AND reviewDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 YEARS)
```

I've tried in several way but every time I use DATE_SUB I get

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'YEARS)' at line 1

or similar errors.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The unit to `INTERVAL` is always *singular* which makes it sound kind of odd when reading the query aloud:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 YEAR)
```

See [`DATE_ADD()` in the reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).